# Name for this M:M pattern

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm, object-relational-model

In Grails there are two ways to do M:M associations. Firstly, have a collection on both sides. GORM will figure out the intermediately table and it is really encapsulated away.

The second way is to have 3 objects, the third object representing the connecting table.  This approach means more code but it also means you can add columns to the actual relationship table very easily.

Is there a name for the second approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any names for these different approaches. From the database point-of-view they aren't really different approaches, because in both cases you have an N:N relationship with a join table (this is what you refer to as "the intermediately [sic] table"), but in one case you have some additional columns (to the foreign keys) in the join table

At the GORM level, the approaches are more obviously different because in one case you have an extra domain class (mapped to the join table), but again, I'm not aware of any specifics names for these different approaches.